# Add spacing between the <li> text and the before content

Tags: css

I want to achieve something like this:

```
000 Lorem ipsum 
    dolor

0   Lorem ipsum 
    dolor
```

This is the code I'm working with:

```
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmo</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li:before {
  content: "0";
}
li:first-child:before {
  content: "000";
}
ul {
  width:100px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Can you help me with CSS to have the text stay equally away from the before content?

"Lorem" and "dolor" need to stay in the same "vertical line".

https://jsfiddle.net/ga6r8qsz/

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use an ordered list <ol> and set the desired indent? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758900/proper-indenting-for-ordered-lists-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using absolute positioning on the `before` elements. This will ensure that your `li` items will remain vertically in line.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

li::before {
  content: "0";
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  left: -35px;
}

li:first-child::before {
  content: "0000";
}

ul {
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmo</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: specifying the width is not really needed if we have no space in the content

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I was playing around with things and it's a left over from that.

Answer (score 1):

make the pseudoelements `::befores` like blocks, in that way you can add the width of them and control the view of the list in that way

here example:

```css
li:before {
  content: "0";
  display:inline-block;
  width:35px;
}
li:first-child:before {
  content: "000";
  display:inline-block;
  width:35px;
}

ul {
  width:300px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text more</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This approach will fail if you make the `ul` width smaller, as the list item text will fall below the `before` element.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `display: flex` property on `li` elements will not only give equal spacing between the `:before` pseudo elements and the `li` tags, but will also make the `li` tags left aligned on new lines as shown below.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
}
li:before {
  content: "0";
  width:70px;
}
li:first-child:before {
  content: "000";
}
ul {
  width:150px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmo</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a great approach!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea where you don't need to use any fixed value for width. Consider a table layout and it will work with any pseudo element content:

```css
li:before {
  content: "0";
  display:table-cell;
  padding-right:5px;
}
li:first-child:before {
  content: "000";
}
ul {
  width:200px;
  list-style: none;
  display:table;
}
li {
  display:table-row;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmo</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit</li>
</ul>
```